# Finding the next element to link clicked by class with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got some HTML markup that looks like this:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slideNextSlidable">Click Here</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="slidable">
    <td>
    <p>Hide me</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And my javascript / jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideNextSlidable').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.slidable').hide();
    });
});​
```

However, this doesn't seem to be getting the `.slidable` `tr`

I'm trying to hide the `.slidable` row that's next (or nearest to) the clicked `.slideNextSlidable` link.

This is nested in a foreach loop (there are many of these rows)

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/Zx5sR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [$.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). From the jQuery API docs:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

And then simply:

```
$('.slideNextSlidable').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('.slidable').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.closest()`

```
$('.slideNextSlidable').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('.slidable').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx5sR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideNextSlidable').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().next('.slidable').hide();
    });
});
```

the 1st parent is the​ `td`, its parent is the `tr`!

Comment: I was one parent() away! lol... Thank you for clearing that up. I'm using closest() though

Comment: no problem! just wanted to make clear that you almost had it ^^